# Web2Py list:reference table, Load and set data

Tags: reference, web2py, data-access-layer

Maybe I'm missing something absurd, I'm not seeing, but this is my first app to study web2py.
I am unable to enter the data in Table Movies, which has fields related to other tables.

The list is loaded, but it is not registered in Movies registration.
Under the codes and the results.

db.py

```
Movie = db.define_table('movies',
 Field('title','string', label = 'Title'),
 Field('date_release','integer', label = 'Date Release'),
 Field('duraction','integer', label = 'Duraction'),
 Field('category','string','list:reference categories', label = 'Category'),
 Field('actor','list:reference actors', label = 'Actor'),
 Field('director','list:reference directors', label = 'Diretor'),
 )

Category = db.define_table('categories',
   Field('title','string', label = 'Title'),
)
```

validators.py

```
Movie.title.requires = [IS_NOT_EMPTY(), IS_NOT_IN_DB(db, 'movies.title')]
Movie.category.requires = IS_IN_DB(db, 'categories.title')
Movie.director.requires = IS_IN_DB(db, 'directors.name')
Movie.actor.requires = IS_IN_DB(db, 'actors.name')
Movie.duraction.requires = IS_INT_IN_RANGE(0, 1000)


Category.title.requires = IS_NOT_EMPTY()
```

movie.py

```
def add():
    form = SQLFORM(Movie)
    if form.process().accepted:
        response.flash = "Successful! New movie added!"
        redirect(URL('add'))
    elif form.errors:
        response.flash = 'Error'
    else:
        response.flash = 'Form, set data'
    return dict(form = form)
```

List Load another tables - ok:

[image]

The items of list not record in DB:

[image: The items of list not record in DB]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The widgets displayed in the form are based on the `IS_IN_DB` field validators you have specified, and there are three problems with the way you have coded them.

First, `list:reference` fields, like standard `reference` type fields, store the record IDs of the records they reference -- they do not store values of other fields within the referenced records. So, the second argument to the `IS_IN_DB` validator should always be the ID field (e.g., `categories.id`).

Second, although the field will store record IDs, you want the form widget to show some other more descriptive representation of each record, so you should specify the "label" argument of the `IS_IN_DB` validator (e.g., `label='%(title)s'`).

Third, `list:reference` fields allow for multiple selections, so you must set the "multiple" argument of the `IS_IN_DB` validator to `True`. This will result in a multi-select widget in the form.

So, the resulting validator should look like this:

```
Movie.category.requires = IS_IN_DB(db, 'categories.id', label='%(title)s', multiple=True)
```

The above will allow multiple `db.categories` IDs to be selected, though the form widget will display category titles rather than the actual IDs.

Now, all of the above can be made much easier if you instead define the referenced tables *before* the `db.movies` table and specify a `format` argument for each table:

```
Category = db.define_table('categories',
   Field('title','string', label = 'Title'),
   format='%(title)s')

Movie = db.define_table('movies',
   ...,
   Field('category', 'list:reference categories', label = 'Category'),
   ...)
```

With the above code, there is no need to explicitly specify the `IS_IN_DB` validator at all, as the `db.movies.category` field will automatically get a default validator exactly like the one specified above (the `format` attribute of the `db.categories` table is used as the `label` argument).

You might want to read the documentation on [`list:reference` fields](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/06/the-database-abstraction-layer#list--type--and-contains) and the [`IS_IN_DB` validator](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/07/forms-and-validators#Database-validators).

As an aside, you might consider specifying your field validators within the table definitions (via the `requires` argument to `Field()`), as this is more concise, keeps all schema-related details in one place, and eliminates the need to read and execute an additional model file on every request.